# how to sort a time field using linq query

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have a table and it has one column like this

```
T1 column with datatype is varchar
------------
10:30 AM,
04:05 PM,
11:08 AM,
08:30 PM,
05:20 PM
```

I want to sort the time using linq query based on time I want show the data in descending order

Answer (score 2):

It is as simple as doing the below

```
var stringToParse = "10:30 AM, 04:05 PM, 11:08 AM, 08:30 PM, 05:20 PM";
var result = stringToParse.Split(new char[]{','})
                          .OrderBy(x=> 
                                   { return DateTime.ParseExact(x.Trim(), "hh:mm tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);});
```

Note by doing this the date portion is defaulted to current date.